# Custom widget designer renders in a modal offscreen

Tags: sitefinity

I am developing a custom widget on a new Sitefinity 12.2 instance. When I define some public properties on my controller as described [here](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/autogenerated-widget-property-editors), my widget designer works as expected. Clicking the edit button on an instance of my widget opens up a full page editor where I can edit my properties.

However, when I define my own widget designer view (following [this documentation](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/create-custom-designer-views-mvc)), the result when I click the edit button is a modal that appears outside of the window above and to the left. Inspecting the element and adjusting the styles through the browser console, I am able to move the modal onscreen where it should be. The css source for the modal's position is [myDomain]/Frontend-Assembly/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend/assets/dist/css/sitefinity-backend.min.css?package=[myProject], which seems to be coming from Sitefinity's default code.

My questions: Is it possible for my default designer views to use the full screen editor that the auto-generated designer uses? If not, what am I doing wrong that's causing my modal to render offscreen? Surely that's not out-of-the-box behavior?

DesignerView.Default.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>This is a custom designer view</label>
</div>
```

DesignerView.Default.json:

```
{
  "priority": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our custom CSS included its own definition for a `.modal` CSS class, which was interfering with the Bootstrap CSS class with the same name used by Sitefinity. This style was the culprit:
`transform: translateY(-50%);`

Removing/renaming our custom class has fixed the issue of the designer modal loading offscreen. I'd still be interested to hear if anyone has an answer for this question though: **Is it possible for my default designer views to use the full screen editor that the auto-generated designer uses?**